# How does autojump capture visited path

Tags: python, bash

Recently I am looking into a really useful tool called  [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump)

In principle, autojump will record the visited path in the database like when user types in "cd ". But how does autojump do that? Is there a program that overwrites cd command? How does autojump trace all visited path in Linux?

Thank you~

Comment: You seem to be having the source for the utility, don't you?

Comment: I do have access to the source code. But I don't know which part captures visited paths. Because when user types in bash command like cd, autojump will run in the background that records the path and updates the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bash autojump uses the `PROMPT_COMMAND` shell variable to execute `autojump_add_to_database` each time just before the next prompt is issued.

look for `# change pwd hook` in [autojump.bash](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/blob/master/bin/autojump.bash)